# psql command not getting execute in bash file

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, ubuntu

I have following code in my bash script to install golang and psql server, I wanted to create a user with username "admin" and password "admin". After running the script, it will entered into psql server but `psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';"` doesn't get execute.

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install golang
echo "Installing required package"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install snapd
snap install go --classic

# Install postgreSQL
echo "Installing postgreSQL"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-client

# Starting database
echo "Starting Database"
sudo service postgresql start
sudo -u postgres psql

# Creating user "admin" with password "admin"
echo "Creating user 'admin' with password 'admin'"
psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';"
```

Comment: Because you run `sudo -u postgres psql` which starts a postgres REPL because you're running `psql`. You probably want `sudo -u postgres` only

Comment: I removed `psql` and this error showed up `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

Comment: Good! Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Comment: there is also error of `sudo usage`, `sudo -u postgres` doesn't connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install golang
echo "Installing required package"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install snapd
snap install go --classic

# Install postgreSQL
echo "Installing postgreSQL"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-client

# Starting database
echo "Starting Database"
sudo service postgresql start

# Creating user "admin" with password "admin"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';"
```

I fixed the problem by removing `sudo -u postgres psql` and using `sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';"` Now it's working good

Answer (score -1):

echo "Starting Database"
sudo service postgresql start

### After this step.(just switch to postgres)

su - postgres

psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';"

Comment: This connected to `postgres@ip-172-31-88-173:~$ ` but still not executing `psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';"`